# How to update symfony context in twig after ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony, elasticsearch, twig

I'm doing a search by filter as you can search an article on an e-commerce by applying some filters.

[image: Text]

*For the page load*:
In the controller I render the twig template with the **context** that contains the filters which the user will use. Let's call this template **temp.html.twig**. In this template I have a `<div id="filter">` and a `<div id="filtered_content">`.

*Applying filters*:
After the user applies some filters; with an ajax call, the search method returns another template with its context (an updated context based on the filters applied) **content.html.twig** that is used to replace the content of  of the temp.html.twig. Everything is fine with replacement of the content div. **But how do I update the twig context with the updated context return by the search?**

**In the controller**

```
public function search(allRepositoryNeeded, Request request){
        // get the filters selected by the user
        $selectedCountries = $request->get("countries");
        $selectedBiologicalStatuses = $request->get("biologicalStatuses");
        $selectedMLSStatuses = $request->get('mlsStatuses');
        $selectedTaxonomies = $request->get('taxonomies');
        if ($request->get('ajax')) {
           // filters
           $accessionsByCountry = $countryRepo->getAccessionsByCountry($selectedBiologicalStatuses);
           $accessionsByBiologicalStatus = $biologicalStatusRepo->getAccessionsByBiologicalStatus();
           
           // I have a new context and I used the "content" key in the ajax response returned
           $context = [
                'title' => 'Accession Filtered List',
                'accessions' => $filteredAccession,
                'accessionsByCountry' => $accessionsByCountry,
                'accessionsByBiologicalStatus' => $accessionsByBiologicalStatus,
            ];
           return new JsonResponse([
                'content' => $this->renderView('search/content_accession.html.twig', $context)
            ]);
        }
        $accessions =  $accessionRepo->findAll();
        $context = [
            'title' => 'Accession List',
            'accessions' => $accessions,
            // filters
            'accessionsByCountry' => $accessionsByCountry,
            'accessionsByBiologicalStatus' => $accessionsByBiologicalStatus,

        ];
        return $this->render('search/index_accession.html.twig', $context);
    }
```

**JS CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // get the filters form
    const filtersForm = document.querySelector("#filters");

    // get the inputs of the form filters
    const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("#filters input");
    
    // add event listener on each input
    inputs.forEach(input => {
        input.addEventListener("change", function() {
            // get the data of the form
            const form = new FormData(filtersForm);
            // create url string params
            const params = new URLSearchParams();
            // loop over the for
            form.forEach((value, key) => {
                params.append(key, value);
            });
            // get the current url
            const currentUrl = new URL(window.location.href);
            // get the ajax query ready
            // using fetch that return a promise
            // add "ajax = 1" so that the same index function in the controller can be used
            fetch(currentUrl.pathname + "?" + params.toString() + "&ajax=1", {
                headers: {
                    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
                }
            }).then(response => response.json()
            ).then(data => {
                // get the div id filtered_content which is to be replaced by the response data
                const filteredContent = document.querySelector("#filtered_content");
                // "content" key coming from the search method result in the controller.
                // it contains the content template with the updated context based on the filters applied.
                filteredContent.innerHTML = data.content;
            }).catch(e => alert(e));
        });
    });
})
```

Note: I have already tried creating a new template for the filters and replacing the filter div with it, but this clears the filters already applied in the search (the checkboxes are no longer checked).

Thank you in advance for your comment.

Comment: As you haven't shared a single line of code, it's impossible to tell you how to do that. What do you mean by "twig context"? And how is your problem related to Elasticsearch?

Comment: You don't need to rerender your filters, you just rerender the part that display the items, e.g. `product-list.twig.html` and replace the corresponding list with the new items

Comment: @NicoHaase I have updated the question with the ajax code.

Comment: @DarkBee I said it in the question, I have tried to do it that way, but anytime you apply a filter, it replaces the content of the filters and also clears the filter already applied.

Comment: @DarkBee
How will you update the other categories list / filters based on the selected one. When one country is checked, I show the categories based on the selected country or countries.  All of them are shown only when no filter is applied.

Comment: What do you mean? If you are talking about the numbers next to the filter, e.g. *Italy (453)*, then we don't know your (database) design. Based on what we can see is that each item is attached to one country, as seen in the column "Country of origin", so I expect these numbers won't change

Comment: If you have multiple filters, which you haven't shown, then what I would do is return something like, `{ 'html': 'the rendered html for products', 'filters': { 'countries' : 'ITA': 123, 'FR': 123, 'UK': 123, }, 'colors': { 'red': 123, 'blue': 123, },}` etc

Comment: @DarkBee The numbers and the filters are to be changed based on the other criteria selected (country, institute, color).  When you select Italy, you can apply more filters only in the objects coming from Italy unless you mix match the country criteria. My problem is not the numbers, I have successfully updated them when I re-render the filters, but I don't want to do that, because anytime I do so, the previously selected criteria are cleared.

Let say you have 5 countries when no filter is applied, once applying color or institute, your originally 5 countries may pass from 5 to 3 and so on

Comment: @DarkBee I understand your point of view, but it's not what I want to do. What I want to do is filter the content and also filter the criteria (filters) based on the selected criteria. I haven't found a way to do it by just updating the context instead of re-render it.

Thank you so much for comments, appreciate !